# SSRS: Dynamic footer alignment for different page sizes

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating PDF report by SSRS, and would like to add footer to it.
My footer contains 3 texts which are placed at the left, middle and right of the page (picture below).

To do this, I have to calculate exactly the position of those textboxes in page, and therefore it fits for only 1 type of page size, A4 in my case, if I export the report in A3, then positions of those textboxes are kept the same as A4, mean that the alignment is not correct anymore.

I tried the solution to add two middle-footers and two right-footers, calculate positions, and hide/show bases on each page size. Then the alignment of footers are correct for both A3 and A4, but creates always blank page in A4 after each page.

Could anyone please share me how to set footer in SSRS which is auto-aligned, independent with page size?

[image: Example of A3 and A4 page footers]